# Can I merge a branch from the future at a commit in the past without merging the shared commits between them, or without cherry-pick?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

Say I have a tag, `v1.5`. More commits were made and another branch `fix` was created at a point ahead of tag `v1.5`.

Now that the fix in `fix` has been made, it needs to be applied to the released version of the code represented by the tagged commit at `1.5`.

**Is it possible, without using `git-cherry-pick`, to merge a large set of commits from `fix` at a given point in the history?**

```
o  ... (history)
|
o  tag v1.5
|
o (can not have in v1.5)
|
o (can not have in v1.5)
|
o (can not have in v1.5)
|\
| \ (`fix` branch)
|  \
|   o (needed at v1.5)
o   | -(can not have in v1.5)
|   o (needed at v1.5)
|   |
|   o (needed at v1.5)
o   | -(can not have in v1.5)
    o (needed at v1.5)
```

Comment: Short answer: No. (Not without cherry-picking)

Comment: Why are you opposed to using `cherry-pick`?  What you're describing *is* cherry picking commits, not merging branches.

Comment: Note that ``git rebase`` _is_ automated cherry-picking.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Simply because of the number of commits that would need to be `cherry-pick`ed. If it were 2 or 3 commits I would not worry about it. However, I didn't realize `cherry-pick` accepted ranges using `..`, as Geoff Reedy's answer indicates!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with rebase instead of cherry-pick. The end result should be the same though regardless of which method is used.

First create a new name for the fix branch so that the original fix branch is left unchanged

```
git branch fixv1.5 fix
```

Then rebase fixv1.5 onto v1.5

```
git rebase --onto v1.5 <upstream> fixv1.5
```

where `<upstream>` should be the SHA of the commit that the fix branch was based on, i.e. the one marked P in the diagram below.

Now you should have a history that looks like:

```
o  ... (history)
|
o  tag v1.5
| \
|  \   A'  B'  C'  D'
|   ---o---o---o---o  fixv1.5
|
o (can not have in v1.5)
|
o (can not have in v1.5)
|
o (can not have in v1.5) P
|\
| \ (`fix` branch)
|  \
|   o (needed at v1.5) A
o   | -(can not have in v1.5)
|   o (needed at v1.5) B
|   |
|   o (needed at v1.5) C
o   | -(can not have in v1.5)
    o (needed at v1.5) D
```

For completeness the equivalent use of cherry-pick would be

```
git checkout -b fixv1.5 v1.5
git cherry-pick <upstream>..fix
```